# Dynamic Cast: Class and String to Comparable

Tags: java, dynamic, casting, dynamic-cast

Instead of trying to trying to put my problem into words, here's some code that demonstrates what I want to do:

```
Class cls = Double.class
String str = "31.4";
Comparable comparableObj null;

comparableObj = (Comparable) cls.cast(str);
```

Any ideas? I've looked at using reflection but with no success.

Comment: It's not _that_ obvious what you're trying to do. Why do you want to cast string value "12" to Integer type?

Comment: If I could somehow get the valueOf(String s) method then everything would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't like what you are trying to do, but here is my modification of your code so that it compiles and runs:

```
Class [] domains = { Integer.class, Double.class, String.class };
String [] stringValues = { "12", "31.4", "dog" };
Comparable [] comparableObjects = { null, null, null };

for (int i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
    Constructor con = domains[i].getConstructor(String.class);
    comparableObjects[i] = (Comparable) con.newInstance(stringValues[i]);
    System.out.println(comparableObjects[i]);
}
```

Prints:

```
12
31.4
dog
```

It might help though if you explain in words what you are trying to achieve, then you might get more help doing it a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to invoke the `valueOf` method of each of these classes. So perhaps:

```
for (int i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
    try {
        comparableObjects[i] = (Comparable) domains[i]
               .getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, stringValues[i]);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        comparableObjects[i] = stringValues[i];
    }
}
```

This code takes the `valueOf` method by reflection. `getMethod(..)` takes the method name and the argument type(s), and `invoke(..)` takes `null` as first argument, because the method is static.

If there are other classes that you want to *convert* from String, you'd have to use their converter methods.

But I don't know whether you actually need this, and why. Since you know all the classes and arguments.